# multi account site - htaccess question

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hey there, i am trying to make a little app that will serve multiple accounts, each one with it's user, etc.

so basically i got:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^$                        index.php  [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d


RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)$                       index.php?account=$1&task=$2&id=$3
```

this works fine for http://sd.domain.com/accountname/index/

but not for: http://sd.domain.com/accountname, is throwing a 404.

so i think i need to just use the variables only when there are present, so i can make something like:

http://sd.domain.com/accountname -- default index controller --

http://sd.domain.com/accountname/index

http://sd.domain.com/accountname/campaigns/

http://sd.domain.com/accountname/view_campaign/5 -- campaign id should be here --

Thanks in advance, hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ index.php?account=$1&task=$2&id=$3
```

Comment: Hello, there, thanks for your help, it is still not working, i get the 404 on http://sd.d.com/act not on http://sd.d.com/act/ on http://sd.d.com/act/task i get fine the task, but onhttp://sd.d.com/act/task/id it fails badly...

Comment: wow..!! just wow..!! thanks man..!!! nice karma from me and my tortuga to you bro...!!!